# How to load more than the standard tools to the grass toolbox?

Tags: qgis

I need to know how I get all the grass tools into the grass toolbox of QGIS. Is there an easy way to do this? I tried the sextante toolbox. After an update sextante doesnt work (python errors). For instance: I need the r.series tool.

mfg

Comment: If'm right both the GRASS toolbox and SEXTANTE use custom functions and windows as a framework for the functions. Therefore someone has to create an entry for your tool first